# Is 64-bit SHA-256 IV-based MAC for fixed-length messages reasonably secure?

Tags: hmac, mac, sha-256, initialization-vector

I want to use `truncate8(SHA256-nopad(IV=secret, message))` as a 64-bit MAC, where `message` is guaranteed to be exactly one hash block long (i.e., 512 bits), and `nopad` means that padding is disabled.

This seems to me to be equivalent in security to `truncate8(SHA256(IV=standard, secret||message))`, except that it is about twice as fast. This makes me suspicious that it might not be as secure, hence this question.

Is there a real reason to use `HMAC` in my use case where the message is always one hash block long?

Comment: IV = secret is really not possible. An IV is supposed to be public and should always change; so you just have a secret. Other issues are the size of the secret size is unknown to us, and that the combination of secret and message is unknown - I guess we can assume concatenation? Because SHA-256 takes just one parameter: a message. 64 bits is generally assumed to weak, even if it is an authentication tag. Finally, without the IV a replay attack seems very feasible.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes By `IV=secret`, I mean that SHA-256 is modified in the MAC generator/checker to start with a randomly-chosen value known only to the MAC generator/checker instead of its usual (publicly-known) `IV`.

Comment: Well, randomly chosen doesn't seem to be a good idea (how would you communicate the random value?), but you could use a ratchet or other key derivation procedure. What's the size of the secret? Note that one hash block still gets padded with the length and at least one padding byte.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes There is no need to communicate the random value, it is just stored in, let's say, "the server". The secret would be the size of the IV for SHA-256, which I believe is the same size as the digest, so 256-bit. Ah, I should also have mentioned the padding is disabled in my variant of SHA-256, will update post.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: they're using the 'secret IV' as the MAC key.  Communicating it is no harder (and no easier) than communicating any other MAC key.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm starting to get it. SHA-256 as you wrote is a block operation and the IV is the initial 256 bit vector of SHA-256 itself? Or is it used as 512 bit input plaintext? Sorry about the many questions, but I'm afraid that this is the confusion that arises if no formal method is used to describe the process.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The secret IV is used as the initial 256 bit vector directly, that's what makes it twice as fast as additionally hashing a secret.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because you can **pre-hash the secret** if you make it one block long. That would basically give you the same performance, but you'd use a generic hash again - excluding the padding. The same goes for HMAC, although in that case another block containing the hash over the ipad + the message has to be processed.